# If else statement does not read user input

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

Whenever the user input is 1 or Jan, the code does not read and jump to second statement and display

> Invalid month has been entered

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a month:  ");

        String month=in.nextLine();


        if((month == "1") || (month == "Jan")){

            System.out.println("Month: January");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid month has been entered");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Strings, use "equals" instead of ==.

```
if(("1".equals(month)) || ("Jan".equals(month)))
```

This is needed because Strings are not primitive types, but a special kind of Objects in Java.

You can check the following for more info:
[What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)